# Linear functionals on a finite dimensional space

Tags: functional-analysis

> Lef $f$ be a linear functional on a finite dimensional space $X$ where $\|f\|=1$. Then since  the closure of $B _X (0,1)$ is compact in $X$, then there is a point $x \in X$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and  $f(x)=1$.

I know this looks pretty straight forward, but can someone make this rigorous for me?
Why such a point exists?

Comment: A continuous function attains its maximum and minimum on compact sets. Or, the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact.

Comment: Yeah, but why $\|x\|=1$ not $\|x\| \le 1$?

Comment: Because $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert$, and with $\lVert f\rVert = 1$, we have thus $\lvert f(x)\rvert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$. So if $\lVert x\rVert < 1$, we can't have $f(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel said we have $\lVert f(x)\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert $ for every $x\in X$.
So if $\lVert x\rVert<1 $ we have $ \lVert f(x)\rVert <1$ for every $x\in X$ which is wrong
because $\lVert f\rVert=\sup\{\lVert f(x)\rVert :\lVert x\rVert \leqslant 1\}$ and the closure of $B _X (0,1)$ is compact so $f$ has maximum in it. Thus there exists $x\in B _X (0,1) $ with $\lVert f(x)\rVert=1$.